# How to access the persistent shared storage of Azure Web Apps For Containers

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-web-app-service

My micro-service will create some files that I need to access, these are mainly archive or error data.

I found the article from here that Microsoft azure app service by default mount persistent shared storage across the container

From Microsoft documentation:

> "You can use the `/home` directory in your app's file system to
> persist files across restarts and share them across instances. The
> `/home` in your app is provided to enable your container app to access
> persistent storage."

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#use-persistent-shared-storage

Now I want to access the `/home` directory to check the files created by the service.

I tried a lot of approaches like using the using FTPS using the  deployment credentials, but I am not able to see the `/home` directory

How I can access the persistent-shared-storage which is mount to the docker container?

I can not configure separate storage to app service as it is in preview mode and not supported for production scenario as per this documentation:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution, Although the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#use-persistent-shared-storage) says By default, persistent storage is enabled, actually it is not.

I doubted this and use the below command to enable the persistent storage and now I can access the files using FileZilla FTPS

Command to enable the persistent storage

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true
```

[image]

Here the Test.txt and Test2.txt are the files create by my app and it is stored to persistent storage and I am able to access them.

Comment: I filed an issue about the inconsistency in the docs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70306

Comment: Where do you configure/find the credentials to access it via FTPS?

Comment: Ok, found the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-configure-credentials?tabs=portal